# React Native (Expo) app can't find local 3D model files on Expo Go

Tags: react-native

I'm building a cool 3D model viewer in my React Native app using Expo. I've got these awesome .obj and .mtl files for my 3D models, and I've placed them in the assets folder as suggested by Expo.

But here's the thing: when I run my app on Expo Go on my phone, it throws this error: "Unable to resolve './assets/Helmet.obj' from 'App.js'". I've checked the path, and it seems right to me.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import ModelView from 'react-native-3d-model-view';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ModelView
        source={{
          obj: require('./assets/Helmet.obj'),
          mtl: require('./assets/Helmet.mtl'),
        }}
        style={styles.model}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  model: {
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
  },
});
```

I'm a bit stuck here. Do you have any ideas on why Expo Go can't find my local 3D model files? Is there something special I need to do when referencing local assets in Expo Go?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you added extensions to config? check  [link](https://www.notjust.dev/blog/2023-02-17-3d-animations-in-react-native-with-threejs-nike-app#rendering-3d-models) and [link](https://github.com/BonnierNews/react-native-3d-model-view#note-using-require)